# Accessing a hash table through a module

Tags: powershell

I have defined this in module as `defblah.ps1`

```
$defblah= @{
        first = "aaa";
        seconf = "bbb";
    }
```

I also have this in module as `Blah.ps1`

```
Function Blah 
{
    Write-Host $defblah.first;
}
```

I did `Export-ModuleMember` and then `Import-Module`, so everything with module definition (export, import) is fine.

Then, after importing I run `Blah`, it prints "aaa", which is what i expected.

The problem is when I type in

```
Write-Host $defblah.first;
```

it returns nothing. How can I make my last statement work and return "aaa"?

Comment: @DaleK , I realized that i put question wrongly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I suggest *not* exporting *variables* from a module, even though it is technically supported.

A module's *implicit* export behavior indeed precludes *variables* - in PSv5+, only *functions* and *aliases* are exported *by default* - meaning the absence of an [`Export-ModuleMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Export-ModuleMembe) and/or [module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/New-ModuleManifest) (`*.psd1`) controlling the exports.

The general expectation is for a module to export *commands* (functions / cmdlets and possibly also aliases), not *data* (variables) - and commands alone present enough potential for name collisions.

If you truly want to export *variables* from your module, use an `Export-ModuleMember` call with the
`-Variable` parameter *and/or* - if your module comes with a *manifest* file - export the variables via the `VariablesToExport` key.